# Access violation writing location dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dynamic-arrays

I am writing a piece of code. As part of this code I have decided to use a dynamically allocated array to store a set of strings. However when i try and assign a value to my array i get the exception

```
Exception thrown at 0x50D540C9 (vcruntime140d.dll) in Glicko2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xC39903E3.
```

From researching this topic it seems that this exception mainly appears if you try and write to outside of your array. However inside the for loop where i am writing it, it should be impossible to write outside of it. The exception happens at the line

```
         posResponsesTeamNames[i] = teamName;
```

and my code is

```
int league::matchSet()
{
    std::string currLine;
    std::string *posResponsesTeamNames = new std::string[league::numTeams];
    std::string posResponsesWon[3] = { "1","2","3" };
    team* team1;
    team* team2;
    bool successful = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < league::numTeams; i++) {
         std::string teamName = league::getName(i + 1);
         for (i = 0; i < teamName.size(); i++) {
             teamName.at(i) = toupper(teamName.at(i));
         }
         posResponsesTeamNames[i] = teamName;   
    }
    std::cout << posResponsesTeamNames[1];
roundStart:
    for (int i = 0; i < league::numMatches; i++) {
        std::cout << "for match " << i + 1 << " please enter name of first team to play: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, currLine);
        int parsed = parseText(currLine, posResponsesTeamNames);
        if (parsed == 2) {
            delete[] posResponsesTeamNames;
            prepForEnd();
            return 2;
        }
        else if (parsed == 0) {
            goto roundStart;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < league::teams.size(); i++) {
            if (currLine == league::teams.at(i).getName()) {
                successful = true;
                team1 = &league::teams.at(i);
            }
        }
        if (successful == false) {
            std::cout << "ERROR: Invalid team name entered";
            goto roundStart;
        }
secondTeam:
        std::cout << "for match " << i + 1 << " please enter name of second team to play: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, currLine);
        parsed = parseText(currLine, posResponsesTeamNames);
        if (parsed == 2) {
            delete[] posResponsesTeamNames;
            prepForEnd();
            return 2;
        }
        else if (parsed == 0) {
            goto secondTeam;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < league::teams.size(); i++) {
            if (currLine == league::teams.at(i).getName()) {
                successful = true;
                team2 = &league::teams.at(i);
            }
        }
        if (successful == false) {
            std::cout << "ERROR: Invalid team name entered";
            goto secondTeam;
        }
whoWon:
        std::cout << "please enter 1 if the first team won, 2 if the second team won or 3 if it was a draw: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, currLine);
        parsed = parseText(currLine, posResponsesWon);
        if (parsed == 2) {
            delete[] posResponsesTeamNames;
            prepForEnd();
            return 2;
        }
        if (parsed == 0) goto whoWon;
    }
    delete[] posResponsesTeamNames;
}
```

Comment: `goto roundStart;` -- Use proper looping constructs such as `for`, `do-while`, break up the code into functions, etc.  Your code is littered with `goto` statements, and very few will want to untangle the spaghetti code.

Comment: You have a for loop inside another for loop that reuses the variable from the outer loop.

Comment: after fixing up my code it turns out it was a result of me accidentally using the same variables inside both for loops. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1    std::string currLine;
2    std::string *posResponsesTeamNames = new std::string[league::numTeams];
3    std::string posResponsesWon[3] = { "1","2","3" };
4    team* team1;
5    team* team2;
6    bool successful = false;
7    for (int i = 0; i < league::numTeams; i++) {
8         std::string teamName = league::getName(i + 1);
9         for (i = 0; i < teamName.size(); i++) {
10             teamName.at(i) = toupper(teamName.at(i));
11        }
12       posResponsesTeamNames[i] = teamName;   
13    }
```

**Assumption**: value of **league::numTeams** is 10

at line no 2 you are creating an array of size 10(league::numTeams).

at line 7, created a local variable counter **i**.

at line 8, creating a local variable  **teamName**

at line 9, assigning 0 to **i**(created at line 7) and started a loop. you are incrementing it in this loop. size of **teamName** may be more than 10(**league::numTeams**). Lets assume 12.

So the value of **i** may be more than 10(league::numTeams). 
Now at line 12, you are assigning value in **posResponsesTeamNames** at position **i** which is **12** now. This assignment will fail for sure.

**Possible Solution**: at line 9, instead using **i**, use **int j** as a second counter on local variable **teamName**

I hope this gives you answer.

Comment: as i said in the comment on the question i ended up realising that it was just from me forgetting to have a separate variable for the second for loop. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the ‘new’ keyword, that is calling your constructor of your class. If your constrictor is instantiating your newly allocated object to null and then, while in your loop you’re de-referencing  that object, that has a tendency to create access violations. If your constrictor is initializing your objects in a way that allows for immediate de-referencing (initialize to empty string “”) that may allow for you to write to that ‘new’ object without access violation.